# Need a Role that can CREATE USER but not allowed to GRANT Predefined Roles in PostgreSQL <16

Tags: postgresql, users, role, kubernetes

We are administrating DB in kubernetes to our customers.
For each new cluster, we create a new user with `CREATE ROLE` and `CREATE DB` roles given to them, so that they can create their own databases and new users with stricter roles.

The problem is, with `CREATE ROLE` permission, the user can GRANT himself `pg_execute_server_program` role, and then use reverse shell attack and then get shell from our pod and read the environment variables, which is not desired. E.g. we have several secrets in env vars that the customer can take advantage of and then increase their attack range and take over more things.

In short, I want to have a user that can create new users, but can't grant himself specific predefined roles.

Update: I looked and found that `ADMIN_OPTION` has been added in PostgreSQL 16 to resolve such issue. My problem is we're using PostgreSQL version 13,14,15 and we can't just force upgrade all clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a workaround with [supautils library](https://github.com/supabase/supautils) which exists just to solve the problem I have here.

As I'm doing this to resolve a security issue, creating functions with `SECURITY DEFINER` may just add another issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use at least PostgreSQL v16. In that version, `CREATEROLE` has been modified so that it doesn't allow you to grant membership in arbitrary roles. You can only grant membership in roles for which you have the `ADMIN` privilege.

With older PostgreSQL versions, you cannot safely give a user `CREATEROLE`.

One way around that could be a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by a superuser that allows the caller to create a role. Make sure to set `search_path` to something safe like `pg_catalog` on that function.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a workaround with earlier versions of postgres. some colleges of mine suggested using trigger events, but I struggle to get it working.

Comment: I have added a potential workaround to the answer.

Comment: I want to mimic all functionalities of CREATE ROLE and that user be able to create new users, alter or drop them, with all arguments, etc. Just prevent granting certain predefined roles like "pg_execute_server_program". I'll be glad if you could give me the function along with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't stuck with only executing `CREATE ROLE` then create a custom function / procedure to allow your customers to create new users. That function would need to be created with `SECURITY DEFINER` permissions and restrict what options could be provided. Obviously the customer's user account wouldn't be able to create users itself.

Comment: I want to mimic all functionalities of CREATE ROLE and that user be able to create new users, alter or drop them, with all arguments, etc. Just prevent granting certain predefined roles like "pg_execute_server_program". I'll be glad if you could give me the function along with a working example.